# Run Gatling simulation files sequentially - Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, gatling

I do have two simulation files and want to run the second simulation file after the first one is done executing. Can you please advise how to get gatling simulations to run sequentially? I am using Gradle as a build tool.

Answer (score 1):

`gradle gatlingRun-FirstSimulation && gradle gatlingRun-SecondSimulation`